# Подсветка кода для gedit

Tags: golang, ubuntu

Как добавить в ubuntu подсветку синтаксиса для gedit, чтобы файлы с расширением go распознавались как код на Go и подсвечивались соответственно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсветки для gedit'а лежат [там](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/gedit/). Для установки скопировать в папку: `/usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs`.